# inventory PSI simulation tool by python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I want to develop monthly basis Inventory similation tool (PSI) by python pandas.

This PSI estimates Inventory qty of month end, which comes from

(Inventory) Inventory of previous month end 
+(IN) Supply of current month
-(OUT) Ship of current month
= (Inventory) Inventory of current month end.

I am struggled how I should code in order to include 2 lines ( or index), because
calculation should start from Inventory of previous month.
I try using for -loop method but encounting error.  Please someone to help to understand the correct coding.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],'IN ':[120,80,60,80,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],'OUT ':[100,50,60,70,120]})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Month')
merged_df['Inventory']=0

for idx, row in merged_df.iterrows():
  merged_df['Inventory'] = merged_df.loc[idx,'IN']+ merged_df.loc[idx,'IN']-merged_df.loc[idx,'OUT']
  
merged_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

You can perform element-wise subtractions using `merged_df['IN'].sub(merged_df['OUT'])`. Pairing it with `cumsum()` to calculate the cumulative sum of the differences obtained in the previous step, effectively accumulating the inventory changes month by month.

```
# Your two dataframes 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],'IN':[120,80,60,80,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],'OUT':[100,50,60,70,120]})

# Merge the dataframes on 'Month' column
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Month')

# Calculate inventory using subtraction and cumulative sum
merged_df['Inventory'] = merged_df['IN'].sub(merged_df['OUT']).cumsum()
```

Comment: Thank you!   I tried your code but encounter other error as "# If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise  KeyError: 'IN'

Comment: Thanks again- I solved myself.   there is space between IN and ' on Dataframe column but it was not considered on the coding.